# Having trouble understanding the resulting format of strptime after converting from dataframe to time series (ts)

Tags: r, dataframe, strptime

When I use strptime function in a dataframe the format of the date looks correct. However, when I then convert to ts (time series) so I can use functions like forecast, the data column looks like gibberish and often hard to see if it is correct or not.  Consider the following code....

```
qtr <- c("03/01/2000","06/01/2000","09/01/2000","12/01/2000","03/01/2001","06/01/2001","09/01/2001","12/01/2001")
qtr <- strptime(as.character(qtr), format = "%m/%d/%Y",tz="EST")
dem <- c(1342,1382,1296, 1330, 1360, 1441,1343,1426)

# create data frame
data <- data.frame(qtr,dem)
data
```

The output from when I type data gives the following:

```
#          qtr  dem
# 1 2000-03-01 1342
# 2 2000-06-01 1382
# 3 2000-09-01 1296
# 4 2000-12-01 1330
```

As expected.  However, when I then convert to a time series as below, i get an extra column.

```
ts=ts(data, start=c(2000,1), end= c(2001,4),frequency=4)
ts
```

output:

```
#          qtr        dem
# 2000 Q1  951886800 1342
# 2000 Q2  959835600 1382
# 2000 Q3  967784400 1296
# 2000 Q4  975646800 1330
```

Also, if I do a view (i.e., View(ts)) I can see only the second and 3rd columns and its difficult to figure out what the dates mean.   What is the format of the middle column?  What do the digits in say 975646800 represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `data$dem` in the ts-object the result should be as you expect.

```r
qtr <- c("03/01/2000","06/01/2000","09/01/2000","12/01/2000","03/01/2001","06/01/2001","09/01/2001","12/01/2001")
qtr <- strptime(as.character(qtr), format = "%m/%d/%Y",tz="EST")
dem <- c(1342,1382,1296, 1330, 1360, 1441,1343,1426)

# create data frame
data <- data.frame(qtr,dem)


myts <- ts(data$dem, start=c(2000, 3), end=c(2001, 12), frequency=4)

myts
#>      Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
#> 2000           1342 1382
#> 2001 1296 1330 1360 1441
#> 2002 1343 1426 1342 1382
#> 2003 1296 1330 1360 1441
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @MarBlo.  It worked for this case. I do notice that when I make the same changes to data imported from a CSV I run into issues.  I think its because the dem series in the dataframe comes in as a factor.  So does the qtr (date) but the strptime fixes it.  how do I fix the data (non date) series?

Comment: Not knowing how you tried to read the csv a first trial probably would be to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. If that fails I recommend to look into `read_csv` from package _readr_ and into `lubridate` which belongs to the tidyverse.  Another helpful literature is https://r4ds.had.co.nz/dates-and-times.html. Please, don't forget to accept the above as an answer, if that helped solving your problem.